# How to remove particular String from text file using java

Tags: java, regex, json, file

I have a text file which consists of json data and I do not need some of the data fields. How do I remove these strings and bring them to another form?

Current Data:

```
[{"EMPTYPE":"21","EMPSUM":"1","VERSION":2.2,"UID":212121,"EMPID":454354,"EMPNAME":"abc","EMPGPRID":123,"AID":121,"DATE":"2015-07-07","EMPGPRID":21}]
```

Required Data:

```
[{"EMPTYPE":"21","EMPID":454354,"EMPNAME":"abc","EMPGPRID":123}]
```

Parser's or delimeters

Comment: why don't your parse only required data which you need?

Comment: See this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Comment: I want to parse it using regex how to do that

Comment: And what's the logic behind which of `"EMPGPRID":123`,`"EMPGPRID":21` you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
"(?!EMP(?:TYPE|ID|NAME|GPRID)")[^"]*":.*?(?:,|(?=}))
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/18

Comment: And the result is `[{"EMPTYPE":"21","EMPID":454354,"EMPNAME":"abc","EMPGPRID":123,"EMPGPRID":21}]`. Required: `[{"EMPTYPE":"21","EMPID":454354,"EMPNAME":"abc","EMPGPRID":123}]`. Unless OP made a mistake...

Comment: ⚠ Let's say there is an `,"AID":121}]` [at the end](https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/17) 

Comment: But how to write replace method,I am getting error;

Comment: @Rakesh use `"\"(?!EMP(?:TYPE|ID|NAME|GPRID)\")[^\"]*\":.*?(?:,|(?=}))"` with `replaceAll()`

Comment: Got it ;But still a , remains

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Jackson for the json parsing (it will take the json string and make more like a regular Java object). It also has a nice remove method you can use (if you know what you don't want) or you can simply make a new object with just the info you like. It's then easy to serialize it back to json.

Comment: I want to parse it using regex how to do that